# BibLaTeX - Sort bibliography by firstpage

Tags: biblatex, sorting

I need to create a bibliography where journal articles within a volume and issue are sorted by the first page number. I can use `\mkfirstpage{pages}` to print the first page of the page range but cannot sort the list by first page. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{library.bib}
@article{articleB,
    author  = {AuthorBLast, AuthorBFirst},
    title   = {TitleB},
    journal = {Journal},
    volume  = {1},
    issue   = {1},
    pages   = {1-6}
}
@article{articleA,
    author  = {AuthorAlast, AuthorAFirst},
    title   = {TitleA},
    journal = {Journal},
    volume  = {1},
    issue   = {1},
    pages   = {13-25}
}
@article{articleC,
    author  = {AuthorCLast, AuthorCFirst},
    title   = {TitleC},
    journal = {Journal},
    volume  = {1},
    issue   = {1},
    pages   = {7-12}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[%
    backend=biber,
    sorting=nty,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{library.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\printbibliography[title=Bibliography]
\end{document}
```

This produces the following:

[image: What I get]

I would like to get

[image: What I need]

I have spent a lot of time with `\DeclareSortingTemplate` with no success. Thanks for help, guidance and pointers in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\mkfirstpage` is a `biblatex`-side command, but sorting happens at the Biber side of things where this command is not available. This means we need to recreate what `\mkfirstpage` does within Biber.

In the source map we extract only the first page from the range and write it into a temporary field for sorting. The example uses `usera`, but one could also define a dedicated field in a new data model.

The sorting template then uses `usera` and pads its value so the number sorts as expected.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[%
  backend=biber,
]{biblatex}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=pages, final]
      \step[fieldset=usera, origfieldval]
      \step[fieldsource=usera,
        match=\regexp{\A\s*(\p{Nd}+)\s*(\p{Pd}+)\s*(\p{Nd}+)\s*\z},
        replace=\regexp{$1}]
    }
  }
}

\DeclareSortingTemplate{jyvnp}{
  \sort{
    \field{presort}
  }
  \sort[final]{
    \field{sortkey}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{journaltitle}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortyear}
    \field{year}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{volume}
    \literal{0}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{number}
    \literal{0}
  }
  \sort{
    \field[padwidth=9]{usera}
    \literal{0}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
}

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{sorting=jyvnp}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{articleB,
  author  = {AuthorBLast, AuthorBFirst},
  title   = {TitleB},
  journal = {Journal},
  year    = {2001},
  volume  = {1},
  number  = {1},
  pages   = {1-6},
}
@article{articleA,
  author  = {AuthorAlast, AuthorAFirst},
  title   = {TitleA},
  journal = {Journal},
  year    = {2001},
  volume  = {1},
  number  = {1},
  pages   = {13-25},
}
@article{articleC,
  author  = {AuthorCLast, AuthorCFirst},
  title   = {TitleC},
  journal = {Journal},
  year    = {2001},
  volume  = {1},
  number  = {1},
  pages   = {7-12},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\printbibliography[title=\bibname]
\end{document}
```

> AuthorBFirst AuthorBLast. “TitleB”. In: Journal 1.1 (2001), pp. 1–6.
>
> AuthorCFirst AuthorCLast. “TitleC”. In: Journal 1.1 (2001), pp. 7–12.
>
> AuthorAFirst AuthorAlast. “TitleA”. In: Journal 1.1 (2001), pp. 13–25.

Comment: Beautiful. I had tried DeclareSourcemap but had no idea how to accomplish what you did with match and replace. I implemented your solution on my production mode file and it works well. Thank you! I am still learning about posting comments. Thanks to everyone for bearing with a novice. I also need to learn how to award badges.